# Is "Proof-of-work" a subset of "Byzantine fault tolerance (BFT)"?

Tags: consensus, proof-of-work, terminology, byzantium

Can we say that `Proof-of-work` is a type of `Byzantine fault tolerance (BFT)` ? In other words, is **PoW** a subset of **BFT** ? Or they are two different categories?

**Please note** that there is a similar question here ([Can Proof of Work be Considered as a Byzantine Fault Tolerance (BFT) consensus algorithm since it addresses the Byzantine Generals Problem as well?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/43926/23024)) but without any answer.

Answer (score 3):

**Byzantine Fault Tolerance**

> Byzantine Fault Tolerance is the characteristic which defines a system
>   that tolerates the class of failures that belong to the Byzantine
>   Generals’ Problem.

**Proof Of Work**

> The big breakthrough when Bitcoin was invented, was the use of
>   Proof-of-Work as a probabilistic solution to the Byzantine Generals
>   Problem as described in depth by Satoshi Nakamoto in this [e-mail](https://www.mail-archive.com/cryptography@metzdowd.com/msg09997.html).

Refer the following post for more details:

https://medium.com/loom-network/understanding-blockchain-fundamentals-part-1-byzantine-fault-tolerance-245f46fe8419